# Azure App Service - Unable to bind SSL cert to custom domain

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, custom-domain

I am trying to bind SSL certificate to my domain in Azure from the below blade:
[image]

When I do, it fails and I can see the following error message in my activity log:

> "Failed to configure SSL Binding for [www.testing.me](http://www.testing.me) with *'thumbprint'* {'Code':'BadRequest','Message':'The name [www.xn--testing-s4a6m.me](http://www.xn--testing-s4a6m.me) is not valid.','Target':null,'Details':[{'Message':'The name www.xn--testing-s4a6m.me is not valid.'},{'Code':'BadRequest'},{'ErrorEntity':{'ExtendedCode':'01003','MessageTemplate':'The name {0} is not valid.','Parameters':['www.xn--testing-s4a6m.me'],'Code':'BadRequest','Message':'The name www.xn--testing-s4a6m.meis not valid.'}}],'Innererror':null}"

As per the error message, SSL binding for [www.testing.me](http://www.testing.me) is failing, but the issue is related to the domain [www.xn--testing-s4a6m.me](http://www.xn--testing-s4a6m.me). I have no idea why this other domain would throw the error when it is not the one to which I am trying to bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message it appears like you have few invalid hostnames ([www.xn--testing-s4a6m.me](http://www.xn--testing-s4a6m.me)). As a first step please try and delete the invalid hostnames and retry the operation.

However, I have seen in the past that one of our customers had multiple invalid hostnames (Involved Puny Codes) in the Custom Domains page on portal, every time they tried deleting an invalid domain, the error message shows a different invalid domain, and it goes on a loop. Hence, our product team deleted the invalid domain names in the backend. Once they are deleted, the customer is unblocked, and he was able to secure his custom domains successfully. PFB example for better understanding:

**Example:** Two custom domains are added to Web App: xn--hello.com and xn--hello2.com. Both of these are invalid.

When trying to delete xn--hello.com, error message returns: "The name [www.xn--hello2.com](http://www.xn--hello2.com) is not valid".

When trying to delete xn--hello2.com, error message returns: "The name [www.xn--hello.com](http://www.xn--hello.com) is not valid".

Hence, it gets stuck in a loop and neither can be deleted.

**Note:** Main root cause of the issue was that puny code (xn-) is not supported in Azure from 2015. It should have thrown an error when you tried to add the Puny code custom domain.

If this is the case with you, please raise a [support request](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/) with in portal so our team can help unblock you.

References:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode